# how to Pass data to a screen defined inside initState?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I was trying to make a single screen with two view that change with index.
I created _pages list inside initState like this.

```dart
class AddPlan extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "addPlan";

  @override
  _AddPlanState createState() => _AddPlanState();
}

class _AddPlanState extends State<AddPlan> {
  List<Object>? _pages;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> _stepVals = {};

  _setSelectedIndex(int newIndex, Map<dynamic, dynamic> newMap) {
    setState(() {
      _stepVals = {..._stepVals, ...newMap};
      _selectedIndex = newIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _pages = [
      StepOne(_setSelectedIndex),
      StepTwo(_stepVals, _setSelectedIndex)
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: _pages![_selectedIndex] as Widget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And from StepOne() widget I call this to pass data and change index.
widget.setNewIndex is my _setSelectedIndex fuction. The name is changed in my StepOne constructor.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
       _formKey.currentState!.save();
       widget.setNewIndex(1, {
         "title": title,
         "age": age,
         "description": description,
         "dificulty": _dificultyIndex,
         "targetMuscles": _targetMuscles,
         "weekDays": indexList,
        });
       }
     },
     child: Container(height: 50, child: Center(child: Text("Next"))),
)
```

This works fine. It changes the _stepVals variable and _selectedIndex inside my main screen.
It also changes to the widget to StepTwo(). But StepTwo widget is not taking the nw value of _stepVals. It appears it is using the initial value of _stepVals that it recieved inside initState. Am I missing something here? I'm new to the language so please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this code to your `setState` or above it to make it work:

```dart
    setState(() {

      // You only need this:
      _pages = [
        StepOne(_setSelectedIndex),
        StepTwo(_stepVals, _setSelectedIndex)
      ];
      // Or this:
      _pages![1] = StepTwo(_stepVals, _setSelectedIndex);

      _stepVals = {..._stepVals, ...newMap};
      _selectedIndex = newIndex;
    });
```

Because `initState` isn't called when the widget rebuilds, it's only called on the first build of the widget, so you need to set the `StepTwo` widget again to make it work.

---

**ANOTHER WAY:**

You can create a function like this:

```dart
  Widget getStep(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return StepOne(index);
      case 1:
        return StepTwo(_stepVals, index);
    }
  }
```

Then add `getStep` to your `build`:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: getStep(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And use your `setState`:

```dart
    setState(() {
      _stepVals = {..._stepVals, ...newMap};
      _selectedIndex = newIndex;
    });
```

You don't need to `initState` any variable.

Comment: Glad to help you out.